# Erro do ListView

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde, estou com um erro que surgiu depois de ter editado uma função de salvar dados pelo DialogFragment, na logCat apresenta o erro que e minha ListView está null, só que não posso tirar o null da classe pois ele não vai reconhecer:

segue o LogCat abaixo:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.allsport.miyonic.allsport, PID: 2933
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.allsport.miyonic.allsport/com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.ResultSimples}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.ResultSimples.onResume(ResultSimples.java:51)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Código java da activity resultado:

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

        import Base.DbHelper;
        import Base.Esporte;

        import static android.os.FileObserver.DELETE;

public class ResultSimples extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lista;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_simples);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaTimes);

        /*apagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DbHelper dd = new DbHelper(ResultSimples.this);
                dd.delete(); // É necessário passar o parâmetro
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        DbHelper dbhe = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Esporte> listaResultPartida = dbhe.selectTodosResult();
        ArrayAdapter<Esporte> adp = new ArrayAdapter<Esporte>(this, R.layout.resultado_modificado, android.R.id.text1, listaResultPartida);

        lista.setAdapter(adp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.resultado_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.deletar) {
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Codigo do DialogFragment :

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import Base.Esporte;

public class DialogGol extends DialogFragment{

    private EditText caixa;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.caixa_jogador_dialog, null);
        caixa = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.caixa_dialog_1);

        AlertDialog.Builder bir = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        bir.setMessage("Gol de ").setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Esporte inseri = new Esporte();
                inseri.setjogadores(caixa.getText().toString());


            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //nulo
            }
        });

        bir.setTitle("Gooolll!!!");

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.caixa_jogador_dialog, null);
        bir.setView(view);

        AlertDialog dialog = bir.create();

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

XML Activity Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.allsport.miyonic.allsport.ResultSimples"
                android:background="#003366">

    <TextView
    android:text="Resultado das Partidas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="29dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15px">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ListaTimes"
    android:textColor="@color/corList"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Obrigado...

Comment: Cadê seu R.layout.activity_result_simples?

Comment: Editei a pergunta coloquei o xml do activity_result_simples e ele se encontra na classe ResultSimples

Comment: Tente colocar o lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaTimes); 
 no início do seu onResume

Comment: @seamusd funcionou não...

Comment: qual a ligação do dialog com a activity e com a lista?

Comment: @Mr_Anderson O botão confirmar salva o nome `String` no banco... a lista tinha criado outra pois tive que personalizar ela (**cor**) e Activity seria onde ele carrega o array do banco dentro da listview.